# Function read_excel() interprets 'Currency' data type completely wrong in one file and good in another

Tags: r, excel, readxl

I have two .xls files and they both containg columns 'Salary' which has values such as $575.000,00 or $2.000.000,00 and so on.

When I use read_excel to read the first file everything is stored fine and the column data types are correct.

However when I read the second file the column 'Salary' is filled with values like 8744-10-06 and 15589-07-13.

I'm not quite sure why that is happening so if anyone has an idea it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have created an .xls file with these values and had no problem reading it with `read_excel` or `read_xls`. I recommend you [to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Clear the formatting from the Excel cells before you import the data to R.